# PHP is today between these dates (exclude year)

Tags: php, date, compare, strtotime

I'm trying to do a simple if echo statement.

```
<?php if (time("mm-dd") > strtotime("11-01") && time("mm-dd") < strtotime("02-28"))echo 'stuff' ?>
```

Basically I want to echo something if today is either Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb. The code works if I use `time()` and the full year but I'd like to just compare the month, day. I think I have some silly syntax error that I just can't figure out. This code snippet is placed in the `<head>` of my html if that makes a difference. Little help. Thanks.

---

This is what I ended up with. Thanks!

```
<?php if ($today > '12-16' || $today < '01-08') echo 'yes' ?>
```

with `$today = date("m-d")`

Comment: Please [don't edit your question and add the solution there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question). Instead, [accept an existing answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), then accept it. This way the question will be marked as solved and other users may benefit from it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the [`date`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function instead of time.
2. Switch `&&` to `||`. No `m-d` date string will ever be both greater than `11-01` and less than `02-28`.
3. You probably want to use an inclusive comparison operator with November 1 and an exclusive one against March 1 to account for leap years.
4. Instead of calling `date()` twice, why not assign the result to a variable?

Here it is all together:

```
$today = date('m-d');
if ($today >= '11-01' || $today < '03-01') { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `date` checking the month only:

```
$month = (int) date("m");
$isMonthCorrect = $month === 11 || $month === 12 || $month === 1 || $month === 2;
```

Note the importance of `(int)`. Integer comparisons are more reliable than string comparisons, even if they behave similarly.

Or if you want to check between two dates, to optimize performance, you should evaluate the dates into timestamps before putting them in code.

For example, you can use some websites for converting Unix timestamps. (Not gonna advertise any here, but you can search "Unix timestamp converter) You can also use `php -r` to get quick output:

```
php -r 'echo strtotime("2016-11-01 00:00:00");'
php -r 'echo strtotime("2017-02-01 00:00:00");'
```

Then you can use them like this:

```
$minimum = 1477958400; // from first command line
$maximum = 1485907200; // from second command line

$isInPeriod = $minimum <= time() && time() <= $maximum;
```

Keep in mind:

1. `time()` always returns the current Unix timestamp, i.e. number of seconds since the Unix Epoch. Use `strtotime` for converting a string to time, and use `date()` to convert a timestamp to a string in a given format.
2. Unix timestamp is always absolute. You can't convert a "month" into a Unix timestamp. You can only obtain the current Unix timestamp with `time()`, or get specific data from the timestamp using `date()`.

References:

- [`strtotime`](https://php.net/strtotime)
- [`time`](https://php.net/time)
- [`date`](https://php.net/date)

Comment: So when comparing dates is it better to compare withe time() or date()?. Or is that just a preference thing? I have some other code using the full date so I compared time() with strtotime("y-m-d") . Works fine but wondering if it's better to convert to date().

Comment: @user5753132, they do different things. `time()` returns a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1, 1970). If that fits your needs, go for it. In this case that's not what you want: your cycle repeats yearly. Since you only care about the month you could use PEMapModder's suggestion of just looking at the month (though I'd probably use something like [`in_array()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead of a bunch of `||`s). My answer is more general (but depending on your range you may need to use `&&` instead of `||`).

Comment: I'm using a list of `||` due to premature optimization of preventing function call overhead. The difference doesn't really matter.

Comment: @PEMapModder, we're off-topic, but it _does_ matter. Readability is much more important than whatever insignificant performance gain you hope to achieve here. The difference wouldn't even show up on any realistic benchmark.

Comment: I would also love to know in what way you believe that "Integer comparisons are more reliable than string comparisons, even if they behave similarly." I don't think there's any truth to that statement, at least in this situation. It is particularly confusing since you get your integers _from strings_.

Comment: @Chris I realize that. That's why I call it _premature_ optimization. And I find an array of three `||`s not very unreadable, that's why I'm using it when I can't choose between the two and OCD forces me to make a choice from a more objective perspective.

Comment: @Chris it is because I'm used to working with mechanisms where my code relies on type-strictness a lot, and casting a supposedly integer to integer asap can ensure other problems don't evolve. Also, as a good practice, this can prevent future problems when you pass the value to somewhere else and you're confused "Oh I though this is a number why is it a string", etc. Just primarily opinion-based, so let's not discuss about code style.

Comment: Especially due to the not-too-perfect design of PHP where many mechanisms are quite undefined (`(bool) "-0"` is true but `(bool) "0"` is false? wtf), I consider more reliable if our assumptions are validated. But again, let's not pull away the topic.

Comment: @user5753132 just remember to always use `time()` when you compare absolute time (before/after), and only use `date()` when you want specific attributes like month, weekday, etc.